# Question regarding sns.barplot and how it works?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn, data-analysis

In Titanic dataset, if I plot 'survived' and 'pclass'

Both are categorical 
survived contains either '0' or '1' 
pclass contains '1','2' or '3'

now when I plot x='survived and y='pclass'

I get this plot

```
sns.barplot(x='pclass',y='survived',data=titanic_df)
```

Survival of the passengers grouped by the class:
[image: Survival of the passengers grouped by the class]

Now how does it plot the survived variable as it is a categorical (0 or 1)? 
Why does the y-axis range from 0 to 0.7?

Comment: You are looking at the average survival rate of each class. That is, the average of all the `0`'s and `1`'s of a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

What you are calculating is a persons chance of survival for each Pclass, for example in your plot a person with Pclass 1 (class 1) has higher surviving probability .

Answer (score 0):

It's because the barplot of seaborn shows the mean value.What's the mean value of a column data full of 0 or 1?The percentage of 1.

Check the doc :https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html
It says "It is also important to keep in mind that a bar plot shows only the mean (or other estimator) value,..."

Best regards.